# Dropdown select not working with single option in Svelte

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5, svelte

I have a dropdown menu in my Svelte application that displays a list of players. I want to be able to search for a player in this list and have the dropdown menu show only the players that match the search query. However, when there is only one matching player in the list, I am unable to select (update) that player from the dropdown menu; but the dropdown menu displays one player. How can I fix this issue?

**Select**

```
<select class="form-select" bind:value={player_id} id="player">
                    {#each players as player}
                        {#if !tournament.players.includes(player._id) && player.name
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())}
                            <option value={player._id}>{player.name}</option>
                        {/if}
                    {/each}
                </select>
```

**Search bar**

```
<input class="rounded line"
 type="text"
 bind:value={searchTerm}
 placeholder="Search for a player"
/>
```

**Update button**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary line"
 on:click={addPlayerToTournament}>Update
</button>
```

**UPDATED Function addPlayertoTournament**

```
function addPlayerToTournament() {
        tournament.players.push(player_id);
        tournament.players = tournament.players;
        axios
            .put(
                "http://localhost:3001/api/tournaments/" + tournament_id,
                tournament
            )
            .then((response) => {
                getTournament();
            });
    }
```

I have tried using the includes function to check if the player's name is included in the search term, and then using an if statement to only show players that meet this condition in the dropdown menu.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Inside `addPlayerToTournament` there's just a `.push()`, maybe missing an assignment here ->  https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive

Comment: If you try to log player id in the ```addPlayerToTournament``` function, do you get a value? It sounds like the issue might have to do with the select element not having a default value. You could add a "disabled" option with the text "please select player" or use ```{# each players as player, i }``` to set the first element to selected if ```i == 0```.

Comment: I did some testing in Svelte REPL, lets say you have two players. When you add first player lets say John, id=1, select is left with one option - player 2. But, player_id doesn't change, it still holds id from John. I'm not sure what is the most elegant way to solve this using Svelte, but you can add default value as @Jelmer suggested or handle player_id yourself in addPlayerToTournament function.

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions :) default is working for me, but the only problem is that bc of the default value it doesn't show me the search suggestion. Any tips? If i delete my search input the suggestion in the select bar will always be the player name. + I am working with the code @Jelmer provided (`{# each players as player, i }`and `i == 0`.

Comment: Can you show this in a Repl?

Comment: @Corrl im a beginner so im not sure what Repl is. Can i use replit and copy the code there? Do you need the Webview? thanks for your time.

Comment: This is the Repl https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.55.0 Could you make an example there showing your problem?

Comment: @Corrl I tried my best but i can't reconstruct my problem. Here is a link to the code [link](https://replit.com/@mirodn/Chess-Project#src/App.svelte) and let me explain some further. Here I can type in the player and he will show up on the select bar, but when i do the same thing on my project, it will show the default value ("please select player"). Maybe it has something to do with my DB? or Function? Thanks again for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm afraid without seeing the code that doesn't work that's hard to debug...

Comment: Playing with this in the Repl I think even while it might look like it's working (visible option changes when searching) the value that's sent when hitting update is not correct. Submitting either 'Bob' or 'Charlie' via searching will log `[1, 1]` so the start value `let player_id = 1;` was added. Here's one way how the logic might work https://svelte.dev/repl/11d4781c8c9d41ed88688b883456d3e5?version=3.55.0

Comment: @Corrl Thank you for your answer, but I encountered 2 problems with that code you provided. 1. If I typ in C and select Czzz as option, it will submit Charlie to the tournament. 2. And bc of the `.push()` and `tournament.players = [...tournament.players, player_id]` code the player will be submitted two times to the tournament (so If im correct I can use only one of them). sry for the inconvenience.

Comment: `.push()`plus assignment or the spread operator line not both together, this are alternative ways to modify the array. Not sure about the other point, will have a look...

Comment: Ok, problem was, that when `player_id` was changed, the function that calculated the array inside the `#each` loop ran. I made a Repl to test out the behaviour https://svelte.dev/repl/220e5ef265ad4579996ab2529649da1c?version=3.55.0 and updated the last link with a new version which I think now works properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251003/discussion-between-user17410204-and-corrl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wanted to thank user @Corrl for all of their help and effort in providing a working solution. I am now able to move forward with my project and I am very grateful for their contributions. I have attached the solution that worked for me in the end, let me know if you have any questions.

**Code Block**

```
<script>
let searchTerm = "";
let selectablePlayers = [];

$: calculateSelectablePlayers(searchTerm, tournament)

function calculateSelectablePlayers(searchTerm, tournament) {
        console.log('calculate - only runs if searchTerm or tournament changes')
        if(searchTerm || tournament.players.length > 0) {
            selectablePlayers = players.filter(player => {
                const notYetInTournament = !tournament.players.includes(player._id)
                const searchTermInName = player.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
                return notYetInTournament && searchTermInName
            })
            if(searchTerm) player_id = selectablePlayers[0]?._id ?? ''
        } else {
            selectablePlayers = players
        }
    }

function addPlayerToTournament() {
        tournament.players = [...tournament.players, player_id];
        player_id = "";
        console.log(tournament.players);
        axios
            .put(
                "http://localhost:3001/api/tournaments/" + tournament_id,
                tournament
            )
            .then((response) => {
                getTournament();
            });
    }

</script>

<body>
      <div>
                <h3>Add Players</h3>
                <!-- Add an input element for the search bar -->
                <div
                    class="input-button-container mb-2"
                    style="display: flex; align-items: center;"
                >
                    <input
                        class="rounded line"
                        type="text"
                        bind:value={searchTerm}
                        placeholder=" Search for a player"
                    />
                    <button
                        class="btn btn-primary line"
                        on:click={addPlayerToTournament} disabled={player_id === ''}>Update</button
                    >
                </div>

                <select class="form-select" bind:value={player_id} id="player">
                    <option value="" disabled>please select player</option>
                    {#each selectablePlayers as player, i}
                        <option value={player._id}>{player.name}</option>
                    {/each}
                </select>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's fine to simply post everything in just one clode block, since it's from one component - less work an better to read :) This is the Repl to the answer https://svelte.dev/repl/046d38b0384343f5bfc2712281b51c23?version=3.55.0